# Broken underwater textures, no leak

Tags: hammer

In the *Hammer Editor*, after I finally fixed a different issue involving "Solid Water", my water is now (mostly) working properly, with an animated surface and proper water physics.

The problem lies in what happens underwater. While above surface, none of the underwater textures show:

[image: Above Water Glitch]

I am happy to lower the water brush down so the sides are not visible from above if need be.

While underwater, 3 of the side textures show. However, a large glass one that looks into a sealed box does not:

[image]

This is happening in another water body as well. I am confident the map doesn't have leaks because the water textures actually work and the compile time has increased by a lot - and the fact that I have completely sealed my skybox.

So, basically, what is causing this issue?

And as a side (but not major) question, how do I change my water to make it, say, more white and visible underwater?

EDIT #1: What I am going to try (I have made it, but not had time to compile it and test it) is making the glass observation wall hollow, then using the structure below

```
| |   | |
|       |
| |   | |
|       |
| |   | |
|       |
| |   | |
```

Where the solid lines are textures (glass) and the dotted ones are Nodraw. This means that only 1 layer of glass is visible (not that the opacity of the glass was the problem). I will post my results when I have tested it.

EDIT #2: Absolutely no better, there is no change. Right now I am testing it with a different texture, but I'm not sure if this will make a difference.

Comment: Do not use nodraw on any surface you can look at. Ever. Putting nodraw on a block will render it completely invisible from that side. So the other sides (and bottom) faces are simply gone and cause vis leaks. Try using some see-through glass pane on the inside panels to avoid those leaks.

Comment: So are you saying that I should use the hollow brush, but apply the textures on the inside? Because I have used a solid brush and put textures on both sides but to no avail - it has the same errors.

Comment: Can you upload a piece of your map with that setting, so I can can look for myself? It's very likely a vis leak, but right now I am unsure where it comes from.

Comment: Aren't Hammer Editor questions off-topic here?  I'd expect they should be asked on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I had a look and I found that the gamedev site does have the Hammer tag, so in future I'll probably ask my questions there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found easy solution!

All you have to do is extend the nodraw texture to a little over the side. One unit will do. This makes it so you see the side instead of the void.

-edit- I just realized this does make the sides void from the other side. So I would only use it if the water is in a hole and not a box.